# How to add new item to listview quickly

Tags: android, sqlite, listview, android-listview

I want to program simple organizer with Notes.

So my solution works, but very bad, because after I create a new note in NewNoteActivity I return to activity with ListView and I see how my list is building again.
I read that listview always will be rebuild, but why it takes so lot of time in my case? For example, in other applications I haven't ever seen the process of drawing list, but in my application I do.

So how to build listview so quickly as it is in good applications? What wrong with my code? I just want to add new item in NewNoteActivity, return to activity with list and see a ready list!

I have a SQLite database with some data as shown below:

```
_id | time | date | text
 1  | 9:45 | 12.01| blabla
 2  | 21:01| 13.01| albalb
 ...| ...  | ...  | ...
```

Also I have a class `Note`:

```
public class Note {
    private int id;
    private String time;
    private String date;
    private String text;
    public Note(final int id, final String time, final String date, final String text){
        setId(id);
        setTime(time);
        setDate(date);
        setText(text);
    }
    public int getId(){
        return id;
    }
    public String getTime(){
        return time;
    }
    public String getDate(){
        return date;
    }
    public String getText(){
        return text;
    }

    void setId(final int id){
        this.id = id;
    }
    void setTime(final String time){
        this.time = time;
    }
    void setDate(final String date){
        this.date = date;
    }
    void setText(final String text){
        this.text = text;
    }
}
```

And NotesManager:

```
public class NotesManager {
    private static final String TABLE_NAME = "NotesListTable";
    private static final String KEY_TIME = "time";
    private static final String KEY_DATE = "date";
    private static final String KEY_TEXT = "text";
    private static final String KEY_ID = "_id";

    private final SQLiteDatabase db;
    public NotesManager(SQLiteDatabase db){
        this.db = db;
    }
    public void save(final ContentValues cv){
        db.insert(TABLE_NAME, null, cv);
    }
    public void delete(final int id){
        db.delete(TABLE_NAME, KEY_ID + "=" + id, null);
    }
    public Note getNoteById(final int id){
        Cursor mCursor = db.query(TABLE_NAME, null, KEY_ID + "=" + id, null, null, null, null, null);
        if (mCursor != null) {
            mCursor.moveToFirst();
        }
        return new Note(mCursor.getInt(mCursor.getColumnIndex(KEY_ID)),
                mCursor.getString(mCursor.getColumnIndex(KEY_TIME)),
                mCursor.getString(mCursor.getColumnIndex(KEY_DATE)),
                mCursor.getString(mCursor.getColumnIndex(KEY_TEXT)));
    }
    public Cursor getAllDataFromDB(){
        return db.query(TABLE_NAME, null, null, null, null, null, null);
    }
    public String[] getKeysArray(){
        return new String[] {KEY_ID, KEY_TIME, KEY_DATE, KEY_TEXT};
    }
}
```

I have a fragment with ListView:
It has been generated by Android Studio, nut I made some changes, added SimpleCursorAdapter

```
public class NotesListFragment extends Fragment implements AbsListView.OnItemClickListener {

    private static final String ARG_SECTION_NUMBER = "section_number";
    private int mSectionNumber = 0;
    private OnFragmentInteractionListener mListener;
    private AbsListView mListView;
    private SimpleCursorAdapter scAdapter;
    private Cursor cursor;
    ImageButton deleteButton;
    NotesManager notesManager = new NotesManager(OrganizerApp.db);

    public static NoesListFragment newInstance(int param1) {
        NoesListFragment fragment = new NotesListFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER, param1);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    public NotesListFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        if (getArguments() != null) {
            mSectionNumber = getArguments().getInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER);
        }
        cursor = NotesManager.getAllDataFromDB();
        //TODO:  startManagingCursor(cursor)

        scAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(getActivity(),
                R.layout.note_list_rowlayout,
                cursor,
                notesManager.getKeysArray(),
                new int[]{R.id.note_list_rowlayout_item1,
                        R.id.note_list_rowlayout_item2,
                        R.id.note_list_rowlayout_item3,
                        R.id.note_list_rowlayout_item4 });
        deleteButton = (ImageButton) getView().
                findViewById(R.id.note_list_rowlayout_deleteButton);
        deleteButton.setOnClickListener(onClickDeleteButton);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_note, container, false);

        // Set the adapter
        mListView = (AbsListView) view.findViewById(android.R.id.list);
        mListView.setAdapter(scAdapter);


        // Set OnItemClickListener so we can be notified on item clicks
        mListView.setOnItemClickListener(this);

        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
        super.onAttach(activity);
        try {
            mSectionNumber = getArguments().getInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER);
            mListener = (OnFragmentInteractionListener) activity;
            ((MainActivity) activity).onSectionAttached(mSectionNumber);
        } catch (ClassCastException e) {
            throw new ClassCastException(activity.toString()
                    + " must implement OnFragmentInteractionListener");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onDetach() {
        super.onDetach();
        mListener = null;
    }


    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        if (null != mListener) {
            // Notify the active callbacks interface (the activity, if the
            // fragment is attached to one) that an item has been selected.
           // mListener.onFragmentInteraction(NotesListContent.ITEMS.get(position).id);
        }
    }

    public void setEmptyText(CharSequence emptyText) { // If list is empty.
        View emptyView = mListView.getEmptyView();

        if (emptyView instanceof TextView) {
            ((TextView) emptyView).setText(emptyText);
        }
    }

    public interface OnFragmentInteractionListener {
        // TODO: Update argument type and name
        public void onFragmentInteraction(String id);
    }

    View.OnClickListener onClickDeleteButton = new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

        }
    };

}
```

I have an activity `NewNoteActivity` in which I create a new note and put it into database:

```
ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();

            cv.put("time", entTime.getText().toString());
            cv.put("date", entDate.getText().toString());
            cv.put("comment", entComment.getText().toString());
            NotesManager.save(cv);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll drop a few hints in here.

As you are using a DB to load data, my thoughts go first to the idea you have a very big number of records you are fetching when creating the list.

Multiply it by 4, the number of views in each listView's item, it may be a reason for the slowdown.

Generally, you'd want to start fetching the data from another Thread, aiming to keep the MainThread light and free(meaning your app will be responsive while the heavy loading takes place).

This can be done via AsyncThread. I'd suggest to pop up a ProgressBar view while you are loading and displaying data, to notify the user your app has work in progress.

Another *GREAT* way to make your listView faster (during scrolling at least, not sure if it can help you on the loading phase), is to implement the ViewHolder pattern in your Adapter.

Each time you scroll, Android calls the getView() method of the Adapter, generally creating a new View each time an item is found(remember, an item has 4 views inside!). This makes it incredibly slow when you handle many items. The idea behind ViewHolder pattern is to re-use views which are no longer visible rather than adding new ones.

You can find more about it [here](http://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/smooth-scrolling.html).

If this still doesn't help, I'd give a try to another way to load.

Having like 1000+ rows from the DB may be an overload of work for what you first need to show.

As an example, let's imagine you have 1000 records to insert in the listView. Loading them all may take some time, and when this is done and the listView is filled, you'll never be able to look at them, simply because your listView has a certain space and on the display you'd be able to see just a little portion of the data, let's say 10.
My point is: why keep the phone busy loading 1000 records on view creation, when you can load let's say 50(thinking over to an early-scroll), and when you know the listView is created and you are able to interact with the app load the rest in a background thread(still, AsyncTask). Once you are done, notify the adapter of the data change.

Hope to have been understandable ^_^"